# Laravel not return the first return

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5

When I extends ApiBaseController in another class, response token denied is doesn't work. even though I put wrong app-token but still give response in another class.

```
class ApiBaseController extends Controller
{
    protected $user;

    public function __construct()
    {

        if (request()->header('app-token') != 'ofdsafalkhguddskjafl01JhBF9mGx2jay'){
            return response()->json([
                'success'=>false,
                'status'=>'401',
                'message'=>'Token Denied !',
                'response'=>[
                    'total'=>0,
                    'data'=>[]
                ]
            ]);
        }
        else{
            $this->user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
        }
    }
}
```

This class still work even though I put wrong app-token

```
class AttendeesApiController extends ApiBaseController
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return Attendee::scope($this->account_id)->paginate($request->get('per_page', 25));
    }
}
```

I want to make sure when app-token is wrong will give `Token Denied !` response
please give me some advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You will have to call parent constructor to make this work.</strike>

```
class AttendeesApiController extends ApiBaseController{
    function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(Request $request){
        return Attendee::scope($this->account_id)->paginate($request->get('per_page', 25));
    }
}
```

If I am not mistaken, you will also have to put a kind of a die in the constructor to avoid further execution.

**Update:**

Best way to handle this is to group these routes inside a middleware and have the bearer token check in the middleware itself. This will make your approach more neat and you can easily add new routes that require bearer token check in this route middleware group.

Comment: i tried using parent::__construct(); but nothing happens. the return still from AttendeesApiController

Comment: @RayCoder `echo` the response and put an `exit` after it. But note that using a middleware is the correct approach as I mentioned in my update.

Comment: what do you mean exit? i'm just confuse using middleware

Comment: @RayCoder can you show me your routes file that has these controllers?

Comment: Reason for downvote would be helpful(to whoever did it).

Comment: **No.** When the constructor of a child class is omitted, there is no need to call the parent constructor; it will be called automatically when constructing the child. This is the same for any method override. The added constructor in your answer does nothing. Also, you don't want any "sort of `die()`" in a controller.

Comment: @istepaniuk Ahh, missed that one completely. Striked that off from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

While it is a good idea to keep the token validation concern separated, it is not a good practice to do such thing in the constructor, let alone hide it in the constructor of a base class.

In general, constructors should be used to construct the object, not to "do things".

Because you want to `return` early, it gets a bit complicated to extract this concern out of the controller. But that's what middleware is for.

Take a look at the [Laravel documentation on creating your own middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware) (altough what you are trying to do might be already built in)

An example middleware class could look like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckToken
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request and check the token.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (...) { //your token check
            return ...; // your early-returned json.
        }

        return $next($request); //otherwise continue
    }
}
```